# Adding items using SPServices issues

Tags: spservices, jquery

Need some assistance on a bit of JQuery for writing to a MOSS 2007 list. I have the following spot of code. If I run it with just the title field, it works fine, adding additional fields doesn't work. The alert note at the bottom shows Status as success and the newID is undefined.

```
    $().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Arrest",
    updates: "<Batch OnError='Continue' PreCalc='TRUE'>" +
                "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>" +
                    "<Field Name='Title'>" + title + "</Field>" +
                    "<Field Name='Date_x0020_of_x0020_Arrest'>" + dateOfArrest + "</Field>" +
                    "<Field Name='Subject_x0020_Information'>" + subjectInfo + "</Field>" +
                    "<Field Name='Charges'>" + charges+ "</Field>" +
                    "<Field Name='Significant_x0020_Activity'>" + sigAct + "</Field>" +
                "</Method>" +
            "</Batch>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        //get the ID for the newly created Issue
        var newID = $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=z:row]").attr("ows_ID");
        alert(Status + " " + newID);
    }
});
```

Date of Arrest is a date field
Subject Information is a multiline note
Charges is a chouce field
Significant Activity is a lookup, and I'm sending it the ID of the item to lookup to.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that James' suggestion is the solution for this issue. Also, check my blog post about the z:row notation: http://sympmarc.com/2011/02/03/issues-with-spservices-and-jquery-1-5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the format of the Date of Arrest string? I needs to be in ISO8601 format, like 2011-02-08T16:42Z (from what I remember) to be added to the list this way, otherwise the whole add operation fails.

Comment: Ahhh... is there is a SPService util for converting a date into this format? Ot an easy way with JQuery?

Comment: Where's it coming from in the first place? Not sure of a method out in the wild, but you could probably do it with some JavaScript jiggery-pokery.

Comment: Test it with a sample date in that format (hard-coded) first, though, to see if I'm right or wrong.

Comment: (third comment! :O ) Just found this linked on a thread in StackOverflow, a Date library! has a toISOString() method: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/